# Silverlight - Open dropdown only clicking on Toggle button

Tags: silverlight

Can anybody tell me how I can open popup by clicking only on Toggle button. Usually, combobox opens popup when you click anywhere. In our project we need to open popup only when user clicks on Toggle button. It's kinda urgent.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a custom control.  This would give you more control over all the parts that make up your combobox.   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/03/22/tutorial-writing-a-templated-silverlight-2-control.aspx